# Geometry Dash Cloud Problem

Tags: geometry-dash

So I get the Steam version of GD, yeah? Then, I re-install it on my iPod touch 5G and I log into my account. Before this, I uploaded my newest data and then loaded it into my game.

But that's not what my problem is. My real problem is that it doesn't have my newest data. Can this be fixed? Also, I now have no devices with my newest data.

Answer (score 1):

Well the correct way on playing with 2 devices is when you start, and your last session was on the other device, you have to load all your cloud data , and when you end the session you upload it.

If you uploaded your steam data and then downloaded it on your phone I dont see why it wouldn't work.

I also have an iPod touch 5g, and it works, even though I don't often play GD on my iPod.

But if you did it the right way this answer doesn't help at all sorry. 
Contact rubrub if you think he could help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it isnt cloud server error. Just on your last device where you used geometry dash with newest data go to Settings > Account > Save. On other device go to Settings > Account > Load and your data is now synced. And as @DOGE said, if you saved your data from new device with noob data, and loaded it on device with your newest data, **YOUR DATAS ARE GONE**. You can ask rubrub (alias robtop (alias Robert Topala)) if he hasnt got backup service on his datacenter server